# Req.body is empty object

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I dont know why did? Help me debug! Please

i try console.log(req.body) and i get {} (empty object)

I tried many ways but I still couldn't understand why.

I tried using middleware but it didn't work either

````
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const pug = require('pug');


app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.set('view engine' , 'pug');
app.set('views', './views');
const low = require('lowdb')
const FileSync = require('lowdb/adapters/FileSync')
const adapter = new FileSync('./db.json')
const db = low(adapter)


app.get('/todos/create', (req, res)=> {
  res.render('create');
});

app.post('/todos/create', (req,res)=> {
  console.log(req.body);
  db.get('todos').push(req.body).write();
  res.redirect('/todos');
});


app.listen(3000);```


this is file create.bug

```h1 Create New List
form(action="/todos/create", method="post", enctype="multipart/form-data")
        .form-group
            label(for="id") Id
            input#id(name="id" type="text")
        .form-group
            label(for="text") Text
            input#text(name="text" type="text")
        button Create```


----------
````

Comment: Do not add spam text to your post to get around the requirement that asks you to explain more of the problem - instead, please *actually explain the problem in more detail*, such as what sort of debugging you've tried that isn't working. It could also be helpful to look up how to create a [MCVE] - consider trimming out code that's not directly related to the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The body-parser module is responsible for parsing data ; you use it in your code, but I don't even see where you import it. You need at least to import it at the top of your file

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
```

See others example of use here : https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser